# SQLite file is not found when i run on the device

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

I have an SQLite database file embedded into my project. On the simulator, querying the database works fine, but not on the device. My database file path when i run on the device is this (as shown on the console with an `NSLog`) :

The path for the database file is : `/var/mobile/Applications/5914F328-148F-52E6-1AC9-38D7FF141F9B/MyApplication.app/db.sqlite`

My relevant code which looks for the DB is:

```
    NSFileManager *fileMgr=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *dbPath=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
    NSLog(@"The path for the database file is : %@",dbPath);//Display the whole path
```

I know that the path on the simulator and on the device are completely different. So how should i change my code above to find my database file relatively?

Comment: Hope this help : [How to get Sqlite database file when application is running on device][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620691/how-to-get-sqlite-database-file-when-application-is-running-on-device

Comment: No, the relative mapping of the path of a file is automatically done by iOS. There is no need to change your code for the device changes. It'll work fine for all the devices(including simulator).

Comment: Ok, but why it's not recognizing the database file when i run on the device, does this mean my code is missing something ?

Answer (score 4):

I solved my issue, for whom that struggle on the same problem, it needs me just to include my SQLite file `db.sqlite` into my Bundle resources. CLick your `project target-->Build Phases--->Copy Bundle Resources` and then hit the `+` button and add your SQLite file or just drag your SQLite file from project Group and files and drop it there. Hope this help :)