# App First Run implementation

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to implement certain activities like Display the Help / tutorials slide show, what is new slide show and download some files and database for the use by the app during the first run after installing the app on the device. Also make some language and other settings.  Is there a method in iOS to do this are there some example or tutorials known to any of you who can share it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSUserDefault to keep track of first launch.

Here is the sample code:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL firstLaunch = [userDefaults boolForKey:<firstLaunchKey>];

if (firstLaunch) {
    <present Help, tip etc.>
    [userDefaults setBool:NO forKey:<firstLaunchKey>];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Will try it implement it and will get back if any thing i am not able to grasp.

Answer (score 0):

1. Some basic ios app tutorials:

   http://www.creativebloq.com/app-design/how-build-app-tutorials-12121473
2. Database -> [How is an iPhone database created for the first time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214147/how-is-an-iphone-database-created-for-the-first-time)
3. Slideshow->

   Three20: https://github.com/facebook/three20 
   and 
   Apple's UICatalog  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html
4. Some Simple code sample for iOS Content storage, sync, management:

   http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-content-ios

Comment: Hi Vignesh, i think your resources are going to be of great help developing this app. will check them out and let you know if any help required thanks a lot.